# Is there a term for when we're okay with criticism from "one of our own."

Tags: single-word-requests

If you think about within a family, for example, everyone might talk very negatively with a specific criticism about a certain family member and all is good. But then the moment that family member's coworker or neighbor down the street states the same exact criticism everyone gets super angry.  The same concept applies to a city, or maybe a singer's fan base.

Basically the concept is if you're one of us you can criticize us with impunity. Otherwise you'll get your butt handed to you.

Is there a term for this?

Comment: I have a few Jewish friends who often tell ethnic jokes about themselves: their culture, religion, habits.  Some of the jokes may even be mildly derogatory.  As we are intimate and long time friends, they don't see anything wrong when I bring a new joke and tell hem.  We will usually laugh together. But I've notice that if a stranger happens to tell them a **similar** joke (usually about being a scrooge or about religion) they will be frowned upon or ignored.  I think your question is about this kind of behavior, which is very common in any society.

Comment: It's like "I'm one of them and I can criticize or make fun, but you can't."

Comment: Exactly. It's a widespread phenomenon, so it's surprises me that there is no common term for it. A colleague at work suggested we make up a word "Iosicbuc" "I'm one so I can, but you can't."